# Error CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'json'

Tags: c#, .net-core, out-parameters, unassigned-variable, null-conditional-operator

I am trying to get value from the `HttpContext` with a key `Correlation-Context`, but I am not sure why I am getting the error while trying to use the variable `json`.

```
internal static CorrelationContext GetCorrelationContext(this IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
{
    return accessor.HttpContext?.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Correlation-Context", out var json) is true
    ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CorrelationContext>(json.FirstOrDefault())
    : null;
}
```

I am getting the error as:

```
Error   CS0165  Use of unassigned local variable 'json'
```

I am using the target framework of `net 5.0`

Comment: If `accessor.HttpContext?.Request` is `null` then `TryGetValue()` never gets executed, leaving `json` unassigned.

Comment: This is too complicated for the definite assignment rules -- even though it's obvious to us that the expression could only be `true` if `accessor.HttpContext?` is not null and thus `.TryGetValue` has executed, it doesn't follow from the (static) assignment rules.

Comment: Arguably the `is true` part would evaluate to `false` in the case that Lance mentioned, but I don't think we can expect the compiler to dig quite so deeply here.

Comment: Works for me; what version of .NET/C# are you using?  I do instead get CS8604 on the `FirstOrDefault()`, as I have Nullable enabled and the version of Newtonsoft.JSON I'm using expects a non-null value to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's obvious to us, I think it's a bit too complicated for the compiler to understand that if `HttpContext` is `null` then the statement will evaluate to `false`.

You can fix your method by moving adding a null check and not using `?.`:

```cs
internal static CorrelationContext GetCorrelationContext(this IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
{
    if (accessor.HttpContext == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return accessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Correlation-Context", out var json)
        ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CorrelationContext>(json.FirstOrDefault())
        : null;
}
```

Comment: so  ` HttpContext? HttpContext { get; set; }` preventing the first part to be excecuted?

Comment: `accessor.HttpContext?.Request` will immediately return `null` if `HttpContext` is `null`. That then leaves the evaluation as `null is true`, which is of course `false`. It would appear that following the logic that far is a bit too much for the compiler at the moment, so it believes that this is a scenario where it could get into the deserialize code without `json` being assigned.